# Quick sort implemented in Python

Tags: python, quick-sort

This code implements quick sort and takes advantage of passing the list by reference. I'm looking for performance and general best practices.

```
import random

def quicksort(array, l=0, r=-1):
    # array is list to sort, array is going to be passed by reference, this is new to me, try not to suck
    # l is the left bound of the array to be acte on
    # r is the right bound of the array to act on

    if r == -1:
        r = len(array)

    # base case
    if r-l <= 1:
        return

    if r == -1:
        r = len(array)

    piviot = int((r-l)*random.random()) + l

    i = l+1 # Barrier between below and above piviot, first higher element
    swap(array, l, piviot) #piviot is now in index l

    for j in range(l+1,r):
        if array[j] < array[l]:
            swap(array, i, j)
            i = i+1

    swap(array, l, i-1) # i-1 is now the piviot

    quicksort(array, l, i-1)
    quicksort(array, i, r)

    return array

def swap(array, a, b):
    # a and b are the indicies of the array to be swapped

    a2 = array[a]
    array[a] = array[b]
    array[b] = a2

    return
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> # array is list to sort, array is going to be passed by reference, this is new to me, try not to suck
> # l is the left bound of the array to be acte on
> # r is the right bound of the array to act on
> ```

A comment like that would be better as a docstring.

---

> ```
> if r == -1:
>     r = len(array)
> ```

You wrote that twice.  The second time is dead code.

---

> ```
> piviot = int((r-l)*random.random()) + l
> ```

The correct spelling is `pivot`.  To generate the random integer, use [`random.randrange(l, r)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).

---

> ```
> def swap(array, a, b):
>     # a and b are the indicies of the array to be swapped
>
>     a2 = array[a]
>     array[a] = array[b]
>     array[b] = a2
>
>     return
> ```

The correct spelling is `indices`.

The `return` is superfluous.  I would omit it.

The swap can be written more simply as `array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]`.  That is simple enough that it might be better not to write a `swap()` function at all.

Comment: Actually, using `int((r-l)*random.random()) + l` is faster than `random.randrange(l,r)`. Could you please explain why you prefer `randrange`? Is it more reliable? "More random"?

Comment: @KurtBourbaki That's interesting. I'm surprised by the huge performance difference. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange), though, `randrange()` produces a more uniform distribution than `int(random() * n)`.